# How to change Macbook Pro (late 2013) screen and top cover

Tags: hardware, macbook-pro, crash, repair

I had an crash accident with my MBPro (late 2013). MB fall down and crashed to its top left  corner. There is a damage to unibody (its not so big problem for me, I can live with it) but there is bigger problem because probably damage of Retina display - when I look at a screen with dark background I can see very tinny and randomly distributed shiny white pixels. It is not much visible but I think it might be some bigger problem with display.

I would like to change the whole top cover. Is it possible to buy this component? Where? Does anybody have some experience with this replacement?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem with my MacBook (as I bought it in such a condition). I bought the screen from eBay. Its quite easy to fix if you follow the instructions on iFixit. You should consider buying only display, not the whole top assembly, as the prices really different. If your top cover is OK, you don't need to buy it, its possible just to change LCD matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it your self, here is a web site that has instructions how to.

https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Teardown/18695

Comment: Do you know where to buy whole MacBook top cover?

Comment: do you have apple service near you

Answer (score -1):

**Apologies**, I misread your question as *NOT* wanting to replace the whole top, only the screen (I probably had this on my mind).

> As mentioned you have the [iFixit guide for whole display assembly replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Display+Assembly+Replacement/27666)

The also sell the part [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Retina-Late-2013-Display-Assembly/IF123-034-1).

Replacing only the screen is much harder than to the whole display assembly. Have a look at this video showing the work involved replacing a screen instead of whole assembly.

> Louis Rossmann - [Macbook Pro Retina screen repair - LCD ONLY for A1502 models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHbdmks-KFE)

I have newfound respect for these repairs, what an epic saga! I can only imagine the power one feels after repairing a device like this :-)

Price of cheapest repair I could find was about 4 times that of a display, the assembly costs about 2 times the display.

You can also have a look [on AliExpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=macbook+retina+display+assembly+13%22) for instance.